# 3d camera control on XY plane controlled by mouse

Tags: 3d, camera, matrix, projection

I am creating a 3d game with a isometric view. I have a problem implementing camera controls. I can control angles of camera, but my view is scrollable only in the XY axis (camera is always up, Z axis). For now controlling camera works but it moves proportionally to the mouse movement. This makes the forward/backward movement much slower than left/right. I would like it to work in such a way that if I have an object under the mouse when I start scrolling, it will also be under the mouse when I finish scrolling the view. I'm guessing the solution to the problem will be a bit of maths and matrices. I've tried to search for some examples but failed. I'm attaching link to video to show how it's working now, if something is not clear I will try to explain more clearly. Please give me some advices how I can solve this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPufuBV04M4